# a simple algebraic linear group on $\mathbb{C}$ is reductive

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I have the definition of simple algebraic group as a group that is connected and that the only normal connected subgroups are the trivial subgroups and a reductive algebraic group over the field of complex number is an algebrai linear group such that every regular representation are semisimple. I don't know how to prove the statement in the title

Comment: A simple algebraic group has trivial unipotent radical, so it is reductive - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830778/on-the-definition-of-a-reductive-group).

Comment: See also [here](https://www.konradvoelkel.com/2012/07/what-is-a-reductive-group/) for a proof.